# How do I manually close jquery-ui tooltip set on table but tooltip created on td using items selector

Tags: jquery-ui, html-table, tooltip

I'm trying to manually close a tooltip. The tooltip is created on a table using the items option to select some td's. When the td is clicked, it should close the tooltip. This doesn't seem to work.

```
<table id="thingtable">
  <tr><td class="thing one">One</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="thing">Two</td></tr>
</table>

$("#thingtable").tooltip({
  items: ".thing",
  content: "Thing"
});

$(".one").click(function (e) {
  $("#thingtable").tooltip("close");
});
```

If I instead add the tooltips directly to the td's, then it works.

```
$(".thing").each(function (index) {
  $(this).tooltip({
    items: ".thing",
     content: "Thing"
  });
});

$(".one").click(function (e) {
  var td = $(e.target);
  td.tooltip("close");
});
```

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/hn4tqzrL/) Clicking on One in the fiddle doesn't close the tooltip, but clicking on Three does.

Having to add a tooltip to each td seems wrong, especially when the table approach works other than this manual close issue. Is that the route I must take?

Comment: I think the issue is that the mouse is still "over" the `td`. This hover keeps it open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the click event, you need to use the `close` and the `disable` methods. The caveat is if you want them to be enabled for use later. Here is a way to do that.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hn4tqzrL/2/

**JavaScript**

```
  $(".one").click(function() {
    console.log("Thing One clicked.");
    $("#thingtable").tooltip("close").tooltip("disable");
  }).hover(function() {
    $("#thingtable").tooltip("enable");
  }, function() {
    $("#thingtable").tooltip("enable");
  });
```

Making use of `.hover()` we can detect when the mouse has moved in and out and trigger the `enable` method. Technically, we do not need to take any action with the `handlerIn` function.

Comment: This works, but it still feels somewhat odd. But I could see the hover keeping it open, thus requiring the workaround.